# Target clicked element only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a simple switch button.
Classes are changing well but when I have multiple instances of this button it doesn't keep the original selection.

Thanks in advance

HTML

```
<ul class="button-switch">
    <li><a href="#" class='active'>Spider-Man</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Iron Man</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Thor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hulk</a></li>
</ul>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.button-switch li a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.button-switch li a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

JS fiddle example
https://jsfiddle.net/t1gsp90j/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the selector which removes the class contextual to the `ul` which contains the `li` that was clicked. Try this:

```
$('.button-switch li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('li a', $(this).closest('ul')).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/t1gsp90j/3/)

`$(this).closest('ul').find('li a').removeClass('active');` would also have the same effect.

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks Rory

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick event removes the class "active" from all elements on the page that match ".button-switch li a", so the current behaviour is to be expected.

What you want is to only remove "active" from siblings of the clicked element:

```js
$('.button-switch li a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(e.target);
    var parentUl = target.closest('.button-switch');
    // Find all links inside the current parent ul element.
    parentUl.find('li a').removeClass('active');
    target.addClass('active');
});
```

Further on i would suggest to rewrite the click event like this for improved performance

```
$('.button-switch').on('click', 'li a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(e.target);
    var parentUl = target.closest('.button-switch');
    // Find all links inside the current parent ul element.
    parentUl.find('li a').removeClass('active');
    target.addClass('active');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Macavity/t1gsp90j/5/